# Checkbox checked shouldn't trigger row click

Tags: checkbox, onclick, datatables

I am using `Jquery Datatable` to display my data and i have a click event on table row where if someone clicks on a row, code takes them to some other page.

Now, I have added a checkbox to every row, but everytime I check/uncheck my checkbox. Its gets triggered as click on row and I go to next page. Is there any way, where I can stop this click event triggering on table row.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click function, check if the event is triggered by a checkbox.

```
$('#table1 tr').click(function (event) {
                var element = $(event.target);
                //Is checkbox?
                if (element.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    window.location = url;
                }
            });
```